# Mongoose populate creating sub document directly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have two mongoose schemas,

Schema A:

```
{
    field1 : { type : [String] }

}
```

Schema B:

```
{
    field2 : { type : ObjectId, ref : 'A' }
}
```

I want to populate mongoose in such a way that i get the following result :

```
{
    field2 : field1 of a documnet from A 
}
```

or

```
{
    field2 : document of A,
    field1 : field1 field of document A
}
```

Example:

Document in A
    {
        _id : 1
        field1 : ["1","2","3"]
    }

Document in B

```
{
    _id : 2
    field2 : 1
}
```

After i populate i want the **result** to be

```
{
    _id : 2
    field2 : ["1","2","3"]
}
```

or

```
{
    _id : 2
    field2 : {_id : 1 , field1 : ["1","2","3"]}
    field1 : ["1","2","3"]
}
```

Any one of the two will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using vitual fields in mongoose.

first populate('field2')
then create a virtual field field1 and set that equal to field2.field1